# Activator.CreateInstance with inherited class not in the same project

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, activator

I have a solution that contains two projects.
First of let me describe my scenario.
Project 1: holds a base class calls MyBaseClass
with the following two property and method that i'm interested in:

TypeToLoad - static string property of which inherited class to instantiate with simple get/set functionality.

Instance - static property which returns a MyBaseClass instance of the type specified in TypeToLoad with the following lines of code:

```
public static MyBaseClass Instance{
   return (MyBaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.typeof(TypeToLoad));
}
```

now in the second project I inherit MyBaseClass as follow(of course proper namespace and references have been added).

```
public class MyInheritClass : MyBaseClass {
    //implements all other functions of MyBaseClass;
}
```

and one of my other code file, in the same project as MyInheritClass, I have the following lines of code:

```
Type myType = Type.typeof("MyInheritClass"); //returns the correct "Type"
MyBaseClass.TypeToLoad = "MyInheritClass";
MyBaseClass myInstance = MyBaseClass.Instance; //Errors... because Type.typeof(...) could not resolve "MyInheritClass".
```

When I move MyInheritClass code file into the same project as MyBaseClass the code runs just fine.

My question is, is there anyway to create and instance of MyInheritClass using MyBaseClass.Instance by setting MyBaseClass.TypeToLoad = "MyInheritClass" without having to have these two classes in the same project (MyBaseClass in the base DLL class library and MyInheritClass in another project referencing MyBaseclass DLL library) ?

I've tried to search for reflections, Activator but wasn't able to find what I was looking for.  Maybe I don't know the correct terminology for this.

Comment: BTW, you should really use descriptive tags like [tag:.net] or [tag:c#]. If you did that, you would most likely get an answer much sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually mean [`Type.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) (and not `Type.typeof()`, which won't compile), then it's clearly documented as doing exactly what you're observing:

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. […] If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

It also explains how to fix it: ad the name of the assembly to the type name. So, if your type is called in `MyInheritClass`, it's in the `MyNamespace` namespace and in `MyAssembly` assembly (usually the same as the project name), you could set the type name to

```
MyNamespace.MyInheritClass, MyAssembly
```

and it should work.

Also, you should avoid using strings for type names, using the actual `Type` objects is much safer. `TypeToLoad` should be of type `Type`, not `string`.

Or, maybe, you shouldn't use a design like this at all. I don't know why are you doing this, but I'm pretty sure there is a better solution that doesn't involve setting static fields on a base class like this. (What happens when you have two types that implement the same base class?)

Comment: Hi svick, you are absolutely right about my mistke of typeing Type.TypeOf() instead of Type.GetType().

Comment: The purpose of me going in this direction is that because I have a  set of providers that would be my base/core with default functionality.  And for each client that I have I would inherit these providers as needed and override their virtual methods where ever needed and in a configuration file point the provider type over to the correct customer provider class.  And I don't want to bunch all customers into the same assembly because it makes no sense to let customer A's library also contains customer B's code.

Comment: Imagine if the number of clients get to 100+, it would be hell to to manage the code set.

By going into this direct, it gives me the capability to develop each client provider separately on their own project and just dump the DLL into their client app and pointing the provider over to client's class.

Something similar to the Membership Providers.

Thank you for your solution/Suggestion.  I'll definitely give this a try and will give feed back on this.  I'm pretty some body other there also has the same issue that i'm having.

Once again, thank you very much.

Thinh P. Nguyen

Comment: svick,

Your solution works like a charm.  All that I have to do was in the configure file change the parameters from

<pageEvents providerType="RepSpark.Web.PageEvents.client1PageEventProvider"/>
To
<pageEvents providerType="RepSpark.Web.PageEvents.client1PageEventProvider, App_Code"/>

as you can tell it's a website project.

Comment: I'm not saying you should put all the code in the same assembly. I'm just saying you might want to use different approach to setting which implementation to use. Have you looked at an IoC container, like [Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx)?